# Change method of encoding characters in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, encoding

I have in my database records which contains Polish characters like: `ś`, `ć`, `ż`, `ź`.

It happen to be a problem for me when I try to execute some of the `SELECT` statements..

Because I get my text but instead of characters I wrote above I get: `<c4><85>`.

I bet there is a way I can change encoding for example for `utf-8`, but how can I do that for simple query like `select * from table`?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? Which SQL tool/GUI do you use to run the `select` statements.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. PostgreSQL version? What client are you using - `psql`, pgadmin3, something else? If `psql`, what platform are you on and what locale is that platform in? There are known problems on Windows with psql on the cmd.exe console.

Comment: im using postgreSQL 8.0 and i am executing my statements in console.

Comment: Closevoted as incomplete. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info for details. Consider editing your question to include relevant detail, or deleting it and writing a more complete one. Also, PostgreSQL 8.0 is amazingly obsolete and totally unsupported.

Comment: Stop using 8.0 (especially if you are on Windows) and upgrade to a supported version ***now***.

Comment: With UTF-8, for Windows console you must use `chcp 65001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've indicated this is on the console, you must first check your console encoding before starting psql.

See [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how) for details of how to do this in windows.

This must be done because even if you do get `psql` to read / write in UTF8 your console won't necessarily understand the characters and will not display them correctly.

Once you've confirmed that your console can accept UTF-8 Encoding then makesure that psql has picked this encoding up:

```
show client_encoding;
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)
```

If that doesn't show UTF-8 then you can use:

```
set client_encoding = UTF8;
```

As a general rule; if your program is expecting to use UTF8 then there is no harm in setting the client encoding blindly (without checking what it is to start with).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html

**Note:**
The above link is for the current version.  As the OP has asked for version 8.0, here is the link for the 8.0 manual:

See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/multibyte.html

Comment: You'll need the `chcp` command too. But really, they're on 8.0...

Comment: Yeah, that's listed on my first link ;-)

Comment: Thought it probably was, just mentioning for searchability as much as anything else and to make sure.